# uib-popover-html won't accept my html string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use the verions 0.14.2 of angular-ui-bootstrap. I was unable to display line returns in the popover.
I use the popover-html directive, and a string such as

```
Limite inférieure<br>Limite supérieure
```

It gives the following error :

```
Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 41-41 [é] in expression [<div>Approchant des limites<br>Limite supérieure: 34:12<br>Limite inférieure: -34:12</div>].
```

I tried wrapping my string in a $sce.trustAsHtml call, but it didn't change a thing.

Here is a plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/3JSly1anPBUiGyqBcsD1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Works for me using `$sce.trustAsHtml` as below.

Note: `trustAsHtml` tells Angular to trust that the HTML is safe, so should only be used if you do trust the HTML, i.e. its not user-supplied.

JS:

```
$scope.popoverContent = $sce.trustAsHtml('Line 1<br>Line2');
```

HTML:

```
<button popover-placement="right" uib-popover-html="popoverContent" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover</button>
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QVymkY9xFCNyUkO66278?p=preview)

Or if your content is dynamic and you need a function:

JS:

```
$scope.input = 'Line 1<br/>Line 2';

var trusted = {};

$scope.getPopoverContent = function(content) {
  return trusted[content] || (trusted[content] = $sce.trustAsHtml(content)); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<button popover-placement="right" uib-popover-html="getPopoverContent(input)" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover</button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tXid1LYI96U3pIyVmmzP?p=preview)

(The reason for caching the value returned by `trustAsHtml` is that `trustAsHtml` always returns a new object so can cause an infinite $digest loop)

Comment: Thank you. this works great, but I don't get the syntax. Why does this not work? $scope.getPopoverContent = function(input) {
  var content = input;
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(content));
}

Comment: It's because of this issue & workaround here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3932

Comment: this solution can lead to cross-site scripting if user-submitted input is displayed.

Comment: And also to memory leak, as the 'trusted' object will be inflated more and more

Answer (score 3):

The accepted approach can easily lead to a cross-site scripting vulnerability in you application. You should really only use `$sce.trustAsHtml` if you explicitly trust the content that you want to display. The angular-bootstrap documentation also hints at that:

> The user is responsible for ensuring the content is safe to put into the DOM!

An alternative and safer approach is to use `uib-popover-template` with a simple template in combination with `ng-bind-html` that automatically uses `$sanitize` to sanitize the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<p uib-popover-template="myPopoverTemplateUrl" 
   popover-trigger="mouseenter" 
   popover-placement="top" 
   popover-append-to-body="true">
        Show a Popover on Hover
</p>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
    <div>
         <p ng-bind-html="popoverContent"></p>
    </div>
</script>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.myPopoverTemplateUrl = "myPopoverTemplate.html";
$scope.popoverContent = "This is HTML <b> And will be sanitized."
```

You also need to make sure to declare `ngSanitize` in your app and to include the `angular-sanitize.js` script. Please take a look at the updated plunker for reference.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ErnIqdvMP0wnp2nTgxr?p=preview)